# syntax for binding multiple variables within text

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, adobe

When binding multiple variables `value1` `value2` `value3` in the same text field, do I do this:

```
text="{some text value1 other text value2 and other text value3}"

or 

text="some text {value1} other text {value2} and other text {value3}"
```

I noticed both work, but which is the right way to do it and will work all the time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend the later for legibility.
It also emphasizes which variables should be set Bindable.